# Keynote equation export to PDF shows different

Tags: pdf, keynote, latex

I am writing an equation with an absolute value:

```
d(c,x)=|c_1-x_1|+|c_2-x_2|
```

In Keynote, it looks good:

[image: Screenshot of the Edit Equation window inside of Keynote with the equation rendered properly with the absolute notation]

But when I export to PDF, the equation becomes

[image: Screenshot of the same equation in a PDF but the absolute notation is not rendered]

(absolute notation is not rendered).

I am using Keynote version 13.2 (7038.0.87). Does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I notice that the pipe characters are also missing when viewed in iCloud/Keynote.  Before Keynote gained the equation feature folks were pasting equations into Keynote as embedded PDFs I believe.  If there's not a fix for this you might try that workaround.

Comment: A temporary workaround: I changed the equation to `d(c,x)=\left|c_1-x_1\right|+\left|c_2-x_2\right|` and it rendered properly in pdf. But hope my original `|c_1-x_1|` equation issue could be reported to some apple guys.

Comment: You can report bugs to apple here: https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/